# 'react-hook-form' form types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I created this form using react hooks form:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  type FormValues = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
  };

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormValues>();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = (data) =>
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input {...register("firstName")} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input {...register("lastName")} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" {...register("email")} />
      </div>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Now typescript enforce me to register input's name (`{...register("name")}`) only using the keys from `FormValues`. If i will remove `email: string;` from `FormValues` then i will get a TS error on `<input type="email" {...register("email")} />` with the next message:

```
Argument of type '"email"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"firstName" | "lastName"'.ts(2345)
```

Question: How to get rig of this issue and to make the inputs name independently from `FormValues`?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ts-forked-wfzjyr?file=/src/index.tsx:735-780

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I see is this:

```
function App() {
  type FormValues = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    // email: string;
  };

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormValues>();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = (data) =>
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input {...register("firstName")} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input {...register("lastName")} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" {...(register as UseFormRegister<any>)("email")} />
      </div>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Basically, you have to type your register as any to not trigger typescript error `<input type="email" {...(register as UseFormRegister<any>)("email")} />`.

Can I ask what you want to achieve exactly, because what you're asking here goes against typescript and react-hook-form principles.

Why would you want to have a form where one field is registered but not treated as one of the fields by typescript ? There might be a much better solution to what you want to do.